# c# Loop through properties to build Expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, tree, expression

I'm actually working on a method that select object which at least one property contains one or multiple words.

The construction of the tree seems correct but The MethodCall fails.

Here's the code:

```
public List<Article> FilterArticle(string expression, ref List<Article> listeArticle)
    {
        IQueryable<Article> queryableData = listeArticle.AsQueryable();
        string[] expressionList = expression.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

        Linq.Expression predicate = null;
        List<Linq.Expression> predicateList = new List<Linq.Expression>();
        int i = 0;

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Article).GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (string ex in expressionList)
            {
                string propertyName = property.Name.ToString();

                ParameterExpression parameterEx = Linq.Expression.Parameter(typeof(Article), "objectProperty");

                MemberExpression propertyEx = Linq.Expression.Property(parameterEx, propertyName);

                MethodInfo toStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");

                MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

                var value = Linq.Expression.Constant(ex, typeof(string));

                Linq.Expression containsMethodExp = Linq.Expression.Call(Linq.Expression.Call(propertyEx, toStringMethod), containsMethod, value);

                predicateList.Add(containsMethodExp);

                if (i == 0) { predicate = predicateList[i]; }
                if (i > 0) predicate = Linq.Expression.Or(predicate, predicateList[i]);

                i = i + 1;

            }
        }



        Func<IEnumerable<Article>, Func<Article, bool>, IEnumerable<Article>> whereDelegate = Enumerable.Where;

        MethodInfo whereMethodInfo = whereDelegate.Method;


        // FAIL
        MethodCallExpression methodCallEx = Linq.Expression.Call(whereMethodInfo, predicate);



        return queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<Article>(methodCallEx).ToList();
    }
```

This line:

```
MethodCallExpression methodCallEx = Linq.Expression.Call(whereMethodInfo, predicate);
```

Send this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for
>   call to method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Colibri.Models.Article]
>   Where[Article](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Colibri.Models.Article],
>   System.Func`2[Colibri.Models.Article,System.Boolean])

'

Thanks for you help.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I added the error message in the original question.